# Find pattern in URL with stringr and regex

Tags: r, regex, extract, stringr

I have a dataframe df with some urls. There are subcategories within the slashes in the URLs I want to extract with stringr and str_extract

My data looks like

```
Text         URL
Hello        www.facebook.com/group1/bla/exy/1234
Test         www.facebook.com/group2/fssas/eda/1234
Text         www.facebook.com/group-sdja/sdsds/adeds/23234
Texter       www.facebook.com/blablabla/sdksds/sdsad
```

I now want to extract everything after .com/ and the next /

I tried  `suburlpattern <- "^.com//{1,20}//$"`
and `df$categories <- str_extract(df$URL, suburlpattern)`

But I only end up with NA in df$categories

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Is it my regex code?

Any help is highly appreciated! Many thanks beforehand.

Comment: `^` in a regex pattern implies it only matches at the beginning of the string. Since `.com` isn't at the start of the url, your pattern won't match. You probably don't need the `^`.

Comment: Thanks Amber, but it unfortunately still does only give me NAs... Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will return everything between the first set of forward slashes

```
library(stringr)
str_match("www.facebook.com/blablabla/sdksds/sdsad", "^[^/]+/(.+?)/")[2]

[1] "blablabla"
```

Comment: You may replace all `\\/` with `/` as  the forward slash is not a special regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `str_extract`, you need a regex that will get the value you need into the whole match, and you will need a `(?<=[.]com/)` lookbehind:

```
(?<=[.]com/)[^/]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFDsFU/1).

**Details**:

- `(?<=[.]com/)` - the current location must be preceded with `.com/` substring
- `[^/]+` - matches 1 or more characters other than `/`.

R demo:

```
> URL = c("www.facebook.com/group1/bla/exy/1234", "www.facebook.com/group2/fssas/eda/1234","www.facebook.com/group-sdja/sdsds/adeds/23234", "www.facebook.com/blablabla/sdksds/sdsad")
> df <- data.frame(URL)
> library(stringr)
> res <- str_extract(df$URL, "(?<=[.]com/)[^/]+")
> res
[1] "group1"     "group2"     "group-sdja" "blablabla"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
library(stringr)
data <- c("www.facebook.com/group1/bla/exy/1234", 
          "www.facebook.com/group2/fssas/eda/1234",
          "www.facebook.com/group-sdja/sdsds/adeds/23234",
          "www.facebook.com/blablabla/sdksds/sdsad")

suburlpattern <- "/(.*?)/" 
categories <- str_extract(data, suburlpattern)
str_sub(categories, start = 2, end = -2)
```

Results:

> [1] "group1"     "group2"     "group-sdja" "blablabla"

Will only get you what's between the first and second slashes... but that seems to be what you want.